# How to pass arguments to pthreads_create that includes both "by value" and "by reference" parts?

Tags: c, pthreads, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have an application, where I need to send both "static" arguments (shouldn't change) and "dynamic" arguments (will be different for each thread) to multiple-threads using `pthreads_create`. I know that I could create separate copies of the arguments structure with different values, but the problem with doing that is the number of threads is specified outside of the application. So I would like to have one structure that has both static (i.e. passed by reference) and dynamic (i.e. passed by value, can be modified in main without affecting value in child thread) parts. In fact, the only variable I need to pass by value is the number of the current thread, since this variable is being incremented in main.

I was thinking that I needed to create a structure that contains both pointers (for stable parts) and non-pointers (for dynamic parts), but then I can't figure out how to pass this structure by reference to `pthreads_create`.

```
struct StableParams {
    int n_threads;
    // other stable parameters
};

struct Args {
    struct StableParams *params;
    int curr_thread;
};
```

...

```
struct Args args; 
...
for(t=1; t <= args.params->n_threads ; t++){

    args.curr_thread = t;
    printf("In main: creating thread %d\n", args.curr_thread);

    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, do_thread, (void *)&args);

}
```

Comment: btw, why set `t+1` ? t is started with 1.

Comment: I am a little unsure about this, but in the code you show args is a struct Args which does not have n_threads, so n_threads must be a part of struct stableParms, so the for statement should have args.params.n_threads or something with an arrow in it instead of one of the dots. Maybe args.params->n_threads.

Comment: sorry, those are both "typos". I tried to simplify the original code, and I made a few mistakes. I will edit.